# Call function in class from non-class function

Tags: python

I basically want to call a function located inside a class from a function which is outside of any class, like the following example code:

```
class something(Gridlayout):
    def func1(self, number1, number2)
        Solution = number1 + number2

def call_func1()
       Something.func1(3, 5)
```

Of course this is only an example this isn't what I want to do, but the point is i tried the code above and it gives the following error:

> TypeError: unbound method func1() must be called with something
>   instance as first argument (got int instance  instead)

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: `func1` is an **instance** method. So you first need to construct a `Something` instance, and then call `func1` on that instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since `func1` is a instance level function, you need to firstly create an object of the class `something` and then use it like:

```
my_object = something()
my_object.func1(3, 5)
```

---

But, as I see that you are not using `self` anywhere within your function, you may probably want to **define it as a static method using [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator** as:

```
@staticmethod
def func1(number1, number2):
    print('Numbers: {}, {}'.format(number1, number2)
```

and then call it the similar way as:

```
my_object = something()
my_object.func1(3, 5)
```

---

OR, if you want t**o access it without creating the object of the class, then you may define it as an class function using [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator** as:

```
@classmethod
def func1(cls, number1, number2):
    #      ^ Reference of class will be passed here, instead of object of class
    print('Numbers: {}, {}'.format(number1, number2)
```

and then you may call it directly using the class as:

```
something.func1(3,5)
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I try to do that..?

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan Add a print statement inside the function and you'll see the function getting called

Comment: Now I have another problem.. I'm trying to call a function which changes the text of a button in kivy from the function your telling me to make static and it's not working (I'm trying to do: self.button1.text = "new text")

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a method which has no reference to `self`. That is, simply a normal function which happens to live on the class. This is known as a static method, and can be constructed via the `staticmethod` decorator:

```
class Something(Gridlayout):
    @staticmethod
    def func1(number1, number2):
        Solution = number1 + number2
        return Solution

def call_func1():
   Solution = Something.func1(3, 5)
   print(Solution)

call_func1()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not import the class to your program. If you are calling `call_func1()` from the same python file that it O.K. but if you declared the class in a python file call something.py and you have a test.py python file from where you are calling `call_func1()`, in that file (test.py) you have to add the below line at the top of the file.

in something.py

```
class something(Gridlayout):
    def func1(self, number1, number2)
        Solution = number1 + number2
        return Solution
```

in test.py

```
from something import Something

def call_func1()
   Something something
   val=something.func1(3, 5)
   print(val)
```

if you declare `func1` as static you can use `Something.func1` no need to instantiate it.

Also in your program I notice one syntax error. You are declaring your class as something(small s) and you are referring it as Something (S capital). Hope this will help you.